# How do you change which IP the NGINX sites-available location config uses from the header?

Tags: nginx, http-headers, cloudflare, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I am only allowing certain IPs through that *sites* particular config. I have multiple configs for multiple sites, as you do.

My example, in sites-available, I have website123.com. I edit this, and see a "server" block, and inside that a "location" block. In the "location" block, I am allow or denying IPs. With multiple

`allow 123.123.123.124`
`allow 123.123.123.125`
`allow 123.123.123.126`

then a `deny all`

Now I am using Cloudflare, it's obviously proxying the IP, but it does include the *True-Client-IP* value in the header. This is now what I need to check for/consider the source in my nginx sites-available sites config.

This seems like a simple change in my sites-available site config to tell it to read a different header value for the IP. Is there a solution I should look at?

I have explored the solution below, but it expects a maintained list of real_ips (Cloudflare IPs). This seems unnecessary, I simply want to change whicih header value nginx looks at. https://danielmiessler.com/blog/getting-real-ip-addresses-using-cloudflare-nginx-and-varnish/

I thought maybe this doc would help, but we need to adjust this *per site config* not a global nginx conf change. https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html

Comment: It is necessary to maintain a list of valid `set_real_ip_from` values otherwise a bad actor could access your server directly and fake the `True-Client-IP` header.